# Create a not connected PublishSubscribeChannel with subflows

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

Long story short: I need to have something like below.

```java
PublishSubscribeChannel firstChannel = new PublishSubscribeSpec(executor).subscribe(subFlow -> ...).get();
```

Is there a way to create a pubsub channel with subflows which is not (yet) connected to any other flow?

The snippet is not working because of `PublishSubscribeSpec(Executor) has protected access in PublishSubscribeSpec`.

I will need to register channels like this dynamically without any information about which flow(s) will be using these channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> has protected access in PublishSubscribeSpec

That was exactly a reason to make it `protected` - to avoid an unusual configuration problem like your. The subflow cannot be provided like this in the plain `PublishSubscribeChannel` definition. It is part of Java DSL parser in the framework to determine such a configuration and register respective beans in the application context. With that explicit `get()` call you just fully eliminate a hook for Java DSL parser to understand your configuration.

> without any information about which flow(s) will be using these channels.

That's not true according your `.subscribe(subFlow ->` intention. Adding a subflow to the `PublishSubscribeSpec` is indeed "an information which flow will be using these channel".

Perhaps we need to look into your business requirement from another angle. There is no reason to be stuck with subflows approach when we simply can use a `PublishSubscribeChannel` from any other place where a `MessageChannel` is needed as an input. I mean if you just create a plain `PublishSubscribeChannel` and then use it for example for the `IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannel)` factory, you'll get the same runtime result as you would expect from those `.subscribe(subFlow ->` connections.